# Gnuplot: break out of loop on keypressed

Tags: loops, gnuplot, break

Is it possible in a GnuPlot 5.2 script, to break out of a loop on a (certain) key being pressed?

```
do for [m=1:6] {      
  do for [i=1:3] {
     do for [fr=0:25] {
        splot 'ex.plt' using 2:3:4 w l lt 1, sprintf("'exm%d.%d'",m,fr)  using 1:2:3 w l lt 3
        set view 69.867, 100.267, 2.503 
        pause 0.05
        break # however: conditionally, on key pressed
     }
  }
}
# break to here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `help bind`.
Probably, you are looking for something like this. The loop will stop when `x` is pressed.

**Code:**

```
### key bind
reset session

bind "x" "Stop = 1"
Stop = 0

do for [i=1:1000] {
    plot sin(i/20.*x)
    print i
    pause 0.25
    if (Stop) {Stop = i;  break}
}

if (Stop) { print sprintf("Stopped after %d iterations", Stop) }
else { print "Time is over..." }

### end of code
```